# Проблемы с выходом из рекурсии

Tags: python, telegram-bot

```
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot("-")
word = "21-30"
fp = "rsp.txt"
@bot.message_handler(commands=["start"])
def start(message):  
    with open(fp, "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
        result = []
        lines = f.readlines()
        for l in range(len(lines)):
            if word in lines[l]:
                result.append((
                    lines[l].replace("\n", ""),
                    lines[l+1].replace("\n", ""),
                    lines[l+2].replace("\n", ""),
                    lines[l+3].replace("\n", "")))
        r = start(message)
        msg = "\n".join([" ".join(m) for m in r])
        bot.send_message(start.chat.id, msg)
    return result
bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Получаю ошибку:

> RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded

Comment: Тут нет выхода из рекурсии, потому и не выходит.

Comment: Это понятно что его нет, я попытался поставить else: return False. Но теперь бот просто молчит, ни ошибок, ни ответа.

Comment: А зачем тут вообще r = start(message)???